# Using JAVA 8 want reduce code for given for each loop logic

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, java-8, java-stream

I am retrieving data from rest API with a object and want copy that to another Response java object.

Currently I have implemented below with normal java

```
public OrganizationalUnitTeamsList getTeamsDetails() {
        List<OrganizationalUnit> organizationalUnitList = organizationalUnitConnector.getOrganizationalUnit();
        OrganizationalUnitTeamsList teamsListResponse = new OrganizationalUnitTeamsList();
        List<TeamDetails> availableTeamList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (OrganizationalUnit organizationalUnit : organizationalUnitList) {
            TeamDetails teams = new TeamDetails();
            teams.setHierarchyLevel(organizationalUnit.getHierarchyLevel());
            teams.setLocationName(organizationalUnit.getLocationName());
            teams.setName(organizationalUnit.getName());
            teams.setShortName(organizationalUnit.getShortName());
            availableTeamList.add(teams);
        }
        teamsListResponse.setTeams(availableTeamList);
        return teamsListResponse;
    }
```

I want above code to be converted in JAVA 8 way.

Can some suggest me more efficient and code concise way to achieve above logic?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: does this code actually work? what is "OrganizationalUnitList" ?

Comment: Fix your software to not having the overlapping of `OrganizationalUnit` and `TeamDetails`, thus eliminating the need to copy information from one to the other.

Comment: In my code I am getting only required data in response pojo so it looks overlapping.However i will try to refactor.Thank you

Comment: Yes the given code is working as expected ,but i want to implement in more efficient way. And about overlapping ,it looks like because only necessary response data i am trying to hold in response DTO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this,

```
List<TeamDetails> availableTeamList = organizationalUnitList.stream()
   .map(this::convertToTeam)
   .collect(collectors.toList());
```

Then define method `convertToTeam` and put the logic of creating new team and populate values there,

```
private TeamDetails convertToTeam(OrganizationalUnit unit){
TeamDetails team = new teamDetails();
// Setters()
return team;
}
```

It will do exactly same thing ,but it looks bit cleaner and also depending on what  your class is doing you could choose to move the method `convertToTeam` to its own class to seperate out the concern.

You should consider renaming this class `OrganizationalUnitTeamsList` to something like `TeamsResponse` it's a unconventional and confusing name for a Class

Comment: that is, if that object is actually a List

Comment: Since organizationalUnitList is a list this code should work ,I'm assuming teamsListResponse is just a Wrapper containing List<TeamsDetails>

Comment: yes, but how do you know it's a List? just having "List" in the name doesn't mean it's a List. Even if it is, it's an empty one, since no data is added to it. If it's a wrapper, it shouldn't work. it should then be for (OrganizationalUnit unit: organizationalUnitList.getList())

Comment: List<OrganizationalUnit> organizationalUnitList = organizationalUnitConnector.getOrganizationalUnit(); this line is loading the list I think you got confused it with teamsListResponse, it's just poor naming of ResponseClass , So loop works but OrganizationalUnitTeamsList is not a good name for Class especially when organizationalUnitList exist in same method

Comment: you're right, I overlooked that line

Comment: Hi All thank you for your inputs here . And yes it is a arraylist object which is holding response from api call.Also I agree that naming of these classes needs to be refactored , i will try to change it to standard naming convention. However suggested solution looks good alternative of my code , will try to implement. Thanks.